# Use Shorewall to port-forward requests based on the domain requested to different servers

Tags: linux, firewall, ip, iproute2, shorewall

How can I get my firewall to port forward traffic that is comming into different domain to different servers.

So I have two web servers. Each one hosts different domains on different servers/IP:

```
first.domain1.com   192.168.1.1  
second.domain2.com  192.168.1.2
```

If a request come in on port 80, all traffic goes to `192.168.1.1`.

I would like have port 80 traffic split based on the destination domain. A request for `first.domain1.com` should go to `192.168.1.1` and a request for `second.domain2.com` should go to `192.168.1.2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorewall (more specifically, `iptables`) works in the [transport layer](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/TCP/IP_reference_model#Transport_Layer) and is not suitable for making decisions based on [application layer](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/TCP/IP_reference_model#Application_Layer) HTTP information. What you want is a [reverse proxy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Reverse_proxy) server. [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) is a good option.